# Does having an ip of 10.0.0.7 mean you are the 7th device on the network, including the router?

Tags: networking, home-networking

My friend online had trouble connecting to the internet. I had them run an ipconfig, and their ip was 10.0.0.56. However, he said he had only about 20 devices hooked up. Do local IP addresses fluctuate like this?

Comment: It depends. Some routers allow you to configure the range of IP addresses given out by DHCP. This allows IPs outside that range to be used for devices required fixed IPs.

Comment: [not worth a new question, too generic] Would a regular consumer all-in-one be expected to cope well with 20 simultaneous devices?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way we could possibly know how IP address assignment happens to work on someone else's network. For all we know, 10.0.0.50 might be the first DHCP address. Or it might be 10.0.0.2. So even if it is strictly sequential, we still can't know.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address being offered will be within the DHCP scope as defined on the server (or router in this case).  They are not necessarily given out sequentially.  As others have said its impossible to comment further without you looking at your DHCP setup, but generally speaking most consumer routers come preconfigured to distribute addresses in the x.x.x.100 and above range.  So to me, it seems like this MAY be a statically assigned address on the laptop side, which could cause connectivity problems if you change networks or routers.

The first step in network troubleshooting is verifying a link.  Next, try pinging something on the local network.